# How do I use exfat drives?

Tags: files

How do I use an exfat-formatted drive, i.e. a flash drive or SD card, with elementary OS? When I try to view it in Files I get an error.

Comment: Here it worked like a charm. Thanks!!!! (on elementary OS)

Answer (score 3):

Exfat support is not included out of the box due to licensing issues. However, you can manually install support for it from the Terminal.

1. Open the Terminal app from the Applications launcher or with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Type the following command, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then enter your password if prompted:

`sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils`

3. Wait for the command to complete, then close and re-open Files to access your drive.

Comment: just instaled it, tried this method, not working

Comment: Closing all "Files" windows was key for me.